# updating subnode value using a second xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to update the value of the subnode "dateEta" from the a second xml file. "identification" is in common on both file.

1.xml

```
<defac>
<fac>
  <identification>170610001-01</identification>
  <order>
   <test1>test</test1>  
   <dateEta>2017-02-03</dateEta>
   <test2>test</test2>
  </order>
</fac>
<fac>
  <identification >170610002-01</identification>
  <order>
   <test1>test</test1>  
   <dateEta>2017-02-03</dateEta>
   <test2>test</test2>
  </order>
</fac>
<fac>
  <identification>170610003-01</identification>
  <order>
   <test1>test</test1>  
   <dateEta>2017-02-03</dateEta>
   <test2>test</test2>
  </order>
</fac>
</defac>
```

2.xml

```
<defac>
<fac>
  <identification>170610001-01</identification>
  <order>
  <dateEta>2017-02-05</dateEta>
  </order>
</fac>
<fac>
  <identification >170610002-01</identification>
  <order>
  <dateEta>2017-01-09</dateEta>
  </order>
</fac>
<fac>
  <identification>170610003-01</identification>
  <order>
  <dateEta>2017-02-08</dateEta>
  </order>
</fac>
</defac>
```

what I want --> update.xml

```
<defac>
    <fac>
      <identification>170610001-01</identification>
      <order>
       <test1>test</test1>  
       <dateEta>2017-02-05</dateEta>
       <test2>test</test2>
      </order>
    </fac>
    <fac>
      <identification >170610002-01</identification>
      <order>
       <test1>test</test1>  
       <dateEta>2017-01-09</dateEta>
       <test2>test</test2>
      </order>
    </fac>
    <fac>
      <identification>170610003-01</identification>
      <order>
       <test1>test</test1>  
       <dateEta>2017-02-08</dateEta>
       <test2>test</test2>
      </order>
    </fac>
    </defac>
```

What I tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="data-uri" select="'2.xml'"/>
    <xsl:param name="data-doc" select="document($data-uri)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dateEta">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="match" select="$data-doc//fac[identification = current()/../identification]/order/dateEta"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$match">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$match"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that’s not working. The date is no updating at all.If "dateEta" is in the same level as "identification" I can make it work but when it's in a lower level nothing happen.

Do you know where I’ve made an error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
<xsl:variable name="match" select="$data-doc//fac[identification = current()/../identification]/order/dateEta"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="match" select="$data-doc//fac[identification = current()/../../identification]/order/dateEta"/>
```

or to:

```
<xsl:variable name="match" select="$data-doc//fac[identification = current()/ancestor::fac/identification]/order/dateEta"/>
```

because `dateEta` is not a sibling of `identification`; its parent `order` is.